# Selenium(PYTHON) click element until no longer clickable

Tags: python, selenium, click, webautomation

So i made a program which includes the entire XPATH of an element, and its supposed to keep clicking the element until it is no longer clickable, but it doesnt seem to work properly, what is wrong here?

```
while True:

    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='trades-container']/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[3]/a").click()
        print("item has been clicked")
    except TimeoutException:
        print("done clicking")
time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you except timeout when you are not using any wait ,

as the element is disabled using class value , use the above method

```
classvalue=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='trades-container']/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[3]/a").get_attribute("class")
 
 while "disable" not in classvalue:       
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='trades-container']/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[3]/a").click()
        print("item has been clicked")
        time.sleep(1)

 print("done clicking")
```

Comment: I think the format and the concept is atleast better with what you wrote, but tho the element is not clickable, when i run it, it continues to print "item has been clicked" even when the element is not clickable, not once does it print "done clicking" whats wrong?

Comment: When its not clickable and you try to click it from script any exception is thrown ?

Comment: it should throw element not interactable if its a disabled element

Comment: yea when its not clickable, the class of the element changes to disabled

Comment: seelnium won't detect class , it detects html attribute disable

Comment: use the above method

Answer (score 0):

*Catching the error* as the element is **no longer clickable** like this, doesn't seem like the best practice.
Instead, you can use the two functions `element.isDisplayed()` and `element.isEnabled()` to check ***if the element's displayed and clickable*** in the document.

Take a look at the documentation for any doubts:

- [isDisplayed()](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/element/isDisplayed/)
- [isEnabled()](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/element/isEnabled/)

**However**, if you would to use ***error exceptions***, you can follow the **[EAFP principle](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp)** and catch an exception being raised by `click()`:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException

try:
    element.click()
except WebDriverException:
    print "Element is not clickable"
```

Comment: Ok, but what if i want to loop click until its no longer clickable?

Comment: Simply using a while loop using these functions: `while element.isDisplayed() and element.isEnabled(): #do stuff ` @ExoticLegend714